# Python invalid syntax...?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to learn Python and Codecademy has been great help. In one of their lessons I made a simplified Battleship game. Now I'm trying to expand on it with adding a second boat, but it gives me a "invalid syntax" error around the "else" of the "while" function. The whole meaning of the "while" function is to find a location on the board for the 2nd boat that isn't already taken by the original boat. All help is appreciated!

```
from random import randint

#Defines the board
board = []
for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

#How it should print the board
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

print ("Let's play Battleship!")
for turn in range(1):
    print ("TURN ", turn + 1)
    break
print_board(board)

#Spawns the boat on a random location on the board
def random_row1(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
def random_col1(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
ship1_row = random_row1(board)
ship1_col = random_col1(board)

#Spawns the 2nd boat
def random_row2(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
def random_col2(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
ship2_row = random_row2(board)
ship2_col = random_col2(board)

#Finds a new location for the 2nd boat if it is already taken by the 1st   
#boat. It procceds with the game when an untapped location has been found.
while ship1_row == ship2_row and ship1_col == ship2_col:
    ship2_row = randint(0, len(board) - 1)
    ship2_col = randint(0, len(board[0] - 1)
else:
    #Debugging
    print ("Ship 1 row: ", ship1_row)
    print ("Ship 1 col: ", ship1_col)
    print (" ")
    print ("Ship 2 row: ", ship2_row)
    print ("Ship 2 col: ", ship2_col)

    for turn in range(4):

        realturn = turn + 1
        guess_row = int(input("Guess row: "))
        guess_col = int(input("Guess colum: "))

        if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
            print ("CONGRATULATIONS! You sunk the battleship!")
            break
        else:
            if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
                print ("Oops, that location isn't even in the ocean!")
            elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
                print ("You guessed that location already!")
            else:
                print ("You missed the battleship!")
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"

            if turn == 3:
                print ("GAME OVER!")
                break

            print (" ")
            print ("TURN ", realturn + 1)
            print_board(board)
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis: `randint(0, len(board[0] - 1))`

Comment: Give the line number as well instead of just saying *'around the "else" of the "while" function'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unbalanced parentheses on the preceding line:

```
ship2_col = randint(0, len(board[0] - 1)
                   ^open  ^open        ^close
```

(two opening and one closing.)